# How to use computed values in typescript enum?

Tags: typescript

```
enum LEVELS {
    ONE = 'one',
    TWO = 'two',
    ALL = [LEVELS.ONE, LEVELS.TWO]
}
```

TS compiler raises the error `Computed values are not permitted in enum with string-valued members`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why does ALL need to be a member of the enum?

Comment: because I want to get all levels by doing `LEVELS.ALL`

Comment: And why do you want to do that? Would the code be so much worse if you wrote `ALL_LEVELS` instead? The problem is that if `ALL` is one of the enum constants then a variable of type `LEVELS` is allowed to take the value `LEVELS.ALL`, which is not what you want.

Comment: As of [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums) *TypeScript provides both numeric and string-based enums.* There is nothing about array as enum members. Can you please clarify how will you use this enum?